# Can I implement a flat Canonical Model in Mule ESB using an XML schema?

Tags: xml, mule

I have a general design question. How I can go about designing/implementing a flat canonical model in Mule? I have an XML message coming that has multiple levels. I need to collapse the XML message to maybe a two level XML (parent & child). I thought of using an XSD to force the XML to conform. Is this possible to do this in Mule? Does anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `xslt-transformer` from the `xml` module in order to transform your original XML to the desired flat canonical form.

The same module offers a `schema-validation-filter` that you can use to ensure the generated XML conforms to the target XSD.

Refer to http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/XML+Module+Reference for more information.

Comment: Thanks David, Wanted to further ask if using JAXB instead of XSLT is a better alternative for this design? I understand XSLT can be heavyweight in terms of memory usage. Could we visualize JAXB to convert incoming XML to Java objects & in terms of response do the reverse transformation?

Comment: XSLT is sure heavyweight but we're not in 1999 anymore :) The only justification for going JAXB is the fact you would generate the bound objects based on the canonical XSD, thus having the guarantee that the generated XML will be valid.

Comment: Thanks again David, I think I will be going with the JAXB approach, however I have one more related question. What is the best way to map a JAXB object in mule to a canonical JAXB object? What I mean is suppose my Mule instance on the inbound gets request for 5 parameters (fname,lastname etc) . I forward that request to the endpoint which returns me 100 fields in a JAXB object. In the meantime I have prepared a canonical JAXB in my layer that is prepared in confirmance with XSD. How best can I map the incoming JAXB to the canonical JAXB in Mule?

Comment: If you use Mule EE, then DataMapper is your friend. Otherwise either use a MEL component or explore Dozer.

Comment: David, unfortunately I am not on Mule EE. I am getting the result back as a list of maps , Is there a simple way in Mule to selectively choose fields & populate the XSD constrained JAXB object. I was thinking to write a custom transformer that will do a containsKey & then a get(K,V) to return the parameters.Is ther a better way?

Comment: I've used `org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanMap` to perform Map <-> Bean mapping in a MEL component and it was working quite well.